# How to set alpha for all objects?

Tags: transparency, dae

blender newb here. I've exported a .dae from Revit using the lumion plugin in Revit and I'm trying to [follow this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoehpxNqCXY).

My issue is that when I import the .dae to blender. Everything shows up black.

In the comments, someone has suggested checking the alpha channels to see if they are all set to 0...which I find to be my case. They then suggest changing all the alpha channels from 0 to anything above.

Here is the alpha setting I am referring to:
[image]

I am finding myself having to go through each blender object and setting the alpha one by one. Is there a faster way to do this besides scripting? also, I have no idea what the alpha setting is for so any insight on that would be appreciated.

I've tried selecting multiple objects and changing but it only changes the last one I selected. I've also tried mouse drag over all and set it but it's still the same result.

Here is what my scene looks like. The black objects have the 0 alpha
[image]

Any help/direction is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean with blender object? do you mean the material?

Comment: @JohnMC, I've updated the question with some images to give it more context. I believe this answers the question. lmk if you need any more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of one besides scripting. Here is a script that should do it:

```
import bpy

for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if not mat.node_tree: continue
    for node in mat.node_tree.nodes:
        if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED':
            soc = node.inputs["Alpha"]
            if soc.is_linked or soc.default_value > 0.01:
                continue
            soc.default_value = 1.0
```

Alpha is a transparency value: 1.0 is opaque and 0.0 is completely transparent. However in Eevee for it to work you must also set the material's "Blend Mode".

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If you want to set a parameter for a *bunch of selected objects* through UI (if they share a same kind of property) just enter the value and while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag the value to set it for all of them</strike>

### Edit

Although it works for any property that share a same address this doesn't work for material properties and it's weird!

Comment: This doesn't work with materials, because they are node-based

Comment: @Crantisz if their nodes be just as same, it works. the concept behind is `.path_resolve()` method and if values have the same address, it should work.

Comment: Nope. Just test it

Comment: @Crantisz I am testing for a set of complex values and it works!

Comment: Test simplest materials.

Comment: @Crantisz You were right. My objects were sharing the same material. but I wonder why blender behaves this way! all other parameters work this way because they share the same path. this is weird!

Thanks for pointing me to this!

Comment: @MohammadHosseinJamshidi, I tried it but it didnt work for me. probably cause i'm newb and selecting objects that are not the same. I'll try on others.

Comment: @Cflux Point of Crantisz was true and my suggested way doesn't work for materials (Although it works for other properties).

I've just kept this answer because others also know about this issue.

Comment: @MohammadHosseinJamshidi understood. Sadly I don't know the difference between Materials and properties yet but I'll get there. I'll be sure to use it when I find out I'm working with properties.